# Which reasoning is used here to prove the zero value for each of the polynomial functions?

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

I am reading a research paper which has a square matrix $\mathbb{G}$ defined as $$\mathbb{G}=[\mathbb{v}~\mathbb{V}_2 ~\mathbb{Q}]$$ where $\mathbb{v}$ is a column matrix with $n$ elements and is equal to $[g_1v_1~g_2v_2~\cdots g_nv_n]^T$. In this case if $\mathbb{G}$ is rank deficient then $\det[\mathbb{G}]=0$ which means $$\det[\mathbb{G}]=\sum_{i=1}^n{g_i}f_i(\mathbb{z,V_2,Q})=0$$ where $\mathbb{z}=[v_1~v_2\cdots v_n]^T$ and $f_i(\mathbb{z,V,Q})$, $i=1\cdots n$, are the co-factors that only depend on $\mathbb{z,V_2,Q}$. Now in that paper it is mentioned that if $\det[\mathbb{G}]$ is $0$ then it is $0$ regardless of the values of $g_i$'s are therefore we can choose all $g_i$'s to be $1$. With this change we have $$\det[\mathbb{G}]=\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(\mathbb{z,V_2,Q})=0$$ After this they say that $\det[\mathbb{G}]=0$ means every $f_i(\mathbb{z,V_2,Q})$ must be zero. I do not understand why every $f_i(\mathbb{z,V_2,Q})$ must be zero (especially when they assume that all $g_i$'s are $1$). Any help in understanding this point will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What dimensions are $\mathbb{V}_2$ and what does $\mathbb{Q}$ mean, the rationals? If so how to multiply these?

Comment: Rather than taking all $g_i$ to be 1, instead observe the result when $g_j$ is chosen to be 1 and $g_i$ is chosen to be 0 for $i\neq j$.

Comment: @Khoross yes I think these values will help. But I wonder why in the paper they assumed all $g_i$'s to be 1.

Comment: @coffeemath no $\mathbb{Q}$ is a matrix and $\mathbb{V_2}$ is also a matrix. They are chosen in such a way that $[\mathbb{V_2} ~\mathbb{Q}]$ has $n$ rows and $n-1$ columns such that $\mathbb{G}$ becomes a square matrix with $n$ rows and $n$ columns.